# Data structure for circular sector in robot vision

Tags: data-structures, computer-vision, distance, robotics, 360-degrees

I'm trying to build a model of a 360-degree view of the surrounding environment from a distance sensor for continuous rotation (radar). I require a data structure for making a quickly computable strategy that will bring a robot to the first clear of obstacles point (or where the obstacle is far away).

I thought to a matrix of 360 numerical elements in which each element represents the detected distance in that degree of circumference.

Do you know a name for this data structure (used in this way)?
There are better representations for the situation I described?

The main language for the controller is Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me that you are aware that your range data is effectively in *polar co-ordinates*.

The uniqueness of working with such 360° is in its circular, “wrap-around” nature.

Many people end up writing their own custom implementation around this data. Their is lots of theory in the robotics literature based on it for smoothing, segmenting, finding features, etc. (for example:  “[Line Extraction in 2D Range Images for Mobile Robotics](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FB%3AJINT.0000038945.55712.65)”.)

Practically speaking, you might want to then consider checking out some robotics libraries. Something like [ARIA](http://robots.mobilerobots.com/wiki/ARIA). Another very good place to start is to use [WeBots](http://www.cyberbotics.com/reference/section3.23) to emulate/model things - including range data - before transferring to a physical robotics platform.